# How to update or insert new data on codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I'm setting up a rest-API on my server, and I want to update a table (i.e "comp_holding_stock"). but every time I test to post new data it returns "No item found"

**Here is my controller**

```
   public function create_comp_holding_stock(){

   $returnArr['status'] = '0';
   $returnArr['response'] = '';

   try {
       if (!$this->input->post()) {
           $returnArr['response'] = "Only POST method is allowed";
       } else {

           $holding_stock_data = array(
               'comp_id' => $this->input->post('comp_id'),
               'customer_id' => $this->input->post('customer_id'),
               'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'),
               'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
           );




           if (!isset($holding_stock_data)) {
            $returnArr['response'] = "Some Parameters are missing";
        } else {

            $customer = $this->Customer->save_holding_stock($holding_stock_data);

            if (!$customer) {
                $returnArr['response'] = 'No items found';
            } else {
                $returnArr['status'] = '1';
                $returnArr['response'] =  $customer;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $returnArr['response'] = "Error in connection";
    $returnArr['error'] = $ex->getMessage();
}
$response = json_encode($returnArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $response;

}
```

**And here is my model below**

```
  public function save_holding_stock($holding_stock_data)
{
    // $this->db->trans_start();

    $success = $this->db->insert('comp_holding_stock', $holding_stock_data);

 return $success;;
}
```

what am i doing wrong? what is the best approach to this scenarios

Comment: i haven't used CI in a long time, but usually, when you use to start a transaction you end it too, or commit

Comment: PD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318749/codeigniter-active-record-insert-if-new-or-update-on-duplicate

Comment: and why do you have both insert and update on the same method? shouldn't you just check the existence first, then decide whether to use an insert or update, and return a true or false based on insert id or affected rows

Comment: After inserting value you should return value as "return 1;" or inserted row's id "return $this->db->insert_id()"

Comment: @AshishSinghal i return success but i got the same respond

Comment: Log the success message  and check if success is returning proper value. before that just set "return 1" and then check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend try to check if you have load model in your controller. 
And in your model try to do this.

```
public function save_holding_stock($holding_stock_data, $comp_id=FALSE)
{

    if(!$comp_id == -1 || !$this->exists($comp_id))
    {
        if($this->db->insert('comp_holding_stock', $holding_stock_data))
        {
            $holding_stock_data['comp_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->db->where('comp_id', $comp_id);

    return $this->db->update('comp_holding_stock', $holding_stock_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes in your code

In your controller,

```
$customer      =   $this->Customer->save_holding_stock($holding_stock_data);
$save_status    =   $this->db->affected_rows();
if ($save_status>0) {
                $returnArr['status'] = '1';
                $returnArr['response'] =  $customer;

            } else {
                $returnArr['response'] = 'No items found';
            }
```

In your model,

```
public function save_holding_stock($holding_stock_data)
{
    // $this->db->trans_start();

     $this->db->insert('comp_holding_stock', $holding_stock_data);

}
```