# trying to update on duplicate key but its not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have this line of sql:

```
$field=array(
 'image'=>$datosArr[0],
 'field'=>$datosArr[1],
 'user_id'=>session()->get("id"),
);      
    
$query = $this->db->table($datosArr[1])->insert($field).' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE image="'.$datosArr[0].'",field="'.$datosArr[1].'"';
```

It works perfectlly when I only need to insert, but it is failing when trying to update,it has an user_id that is primary key, so I hope thats what gets on the key, the other array variables $datosArr are strings, any ideas?

Basically im trying to update when user_id exists , I want to update field and image when user_id already exists.

Database contains user_id (Primary Key), field and image which both are varchar, thanks

Comment: You need to supply an id so that a duplicate can be recognised.

Comment: @P.Salmon but I dont want it to get the id as the key, thats why i have user_id with unique

Comment: Basically im trying to update when user_id exists having an autoincrement id - ?? Please add table definition.

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, I have edited the question, it is right know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here, it works for Codeigniter 4, I dont know the lowest version that can do it, but it works fine.
[CodeIgniter- active record insert if new or update on duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318749/codeigniter-active-record-insert-if-new-or-update-on-duplicate)

Comment: Accept your answer so that future readers will instantly know that the answer works :)